# Can I use vector map with angular google maps (Agm) and typescript?

Tags: google-maps-api-2, agm

I want to create a vector map with angular google maps and I don't know if it is possible. I'm using styles directive from AGM to give the map the style I want, but I want the map to be a vector one. Can I do it? Thank you!